# how can i display foreignkey data in a different html template?. Btw im new to django, so it's a bit confusing for me

Tags: python, django

**my views.py**

```
def schedule_work(request):
    form = schedule_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = schedule_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('view_schedulework')
    return render(request, 'schedule_work.html', {'form': form})


def view_schedulework(request):
    data = schedule.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'view_schedulework.html', {'data': data})


def update_schedulework(request, id):
    data = schedule.objects.get(id=id)
    form = schedule_form(instance=data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = schedule_form(request.POST or None, instance=data or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('view_schedulework')
    return render(request, 'edit_schedulework.html', {'form': form})


def delete_schedulework(request, id):
    schedule.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    return redirect('view_schedulework')


def available_schedules(request):
    data = appointment.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'available_schedules.html', {'data': data})
```

**my models.py**

```
class customuser(AbstractUser):
    is_worker = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile', null=True)


class schedule(models.Model):
    date_available = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True)


class appointment(models.Model):
    Customuser = models.ForeignKey(customuser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Schedule = models.ForeignKey(schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**my html template for available_schedules**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sl No.</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>Available Date</th>
          <th>Starting Time</th>
          <th>Ending Time</th>
          <th>Schedule an appointment</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for appointment in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
          <td>{{ appointment.Customuser.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ appointment.Schedule.date_available }}</td>
          <td>{{ appointment.Schedule.start_time }}</td>
          <td>{{ appointment.Schedule.end_time }}</td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Book appointment</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

im trying to display the data in models 'schedule and customuser' into model 'appointment' with foreignkey.But its not working,please help. i need to loop all the details in schedule and customuser.username through appointment and display that in my available_schedule.html instead just showing in the schedule data in view_schedulework html.